# System.ExecutionEngineException being thrown

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

This exception is being thrown when this line of code gets executed

```
retobj = Marshal.PtrToStructure( buffer, anytype );
```

I don't know what is causing this because, the application I am attempting to run works fine on other developers machines here.

```
public static object RawDeserialize(byte[] rawdatas, Type anytype) 
{
    int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(anytype);

    if (rawsize > rawdatas.Length)
    {  
        return null;
    }

    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
    object retobj = null;

    try 
    {
         Marshal.Copy(rawdatas, 0, buffer, rawsize);
         retobj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, anytype);
    }
    finally 
    {
         Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    }

    return retobj;
}
```

I've tried repairing the .NET Compact Framework multiple times and nothing seems to work, does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: Provide more information about the exception (and any `InnerException`).

Comment: Does the exception have any more information in the InnerException?

Comment: The inner exception is null.

`public static object RawDeserialize( byte[] rawdatas, Type anytype )
  {
   int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf( anytype );
   if( rawsize > rawdatas.Length )
    return null;
   IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( rawsize );
   
   object retobj = null;
   try
   {
    Marshal.Copy( rawdatas, 0, buffer, rawsize );
    retobj = Marshal.PtrToStructure( buffer, anytype );
   }
   finally
   {
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal( buffer );
   }
   return retobj;
  }`

This is the function where the line is contained.  Other than that i cant provide any more information.

Comment: What type of object are you trying to create here? Can you post the struct or class definition of the thing you're trying to create?

Comment: @user501211, is it possible to post the `stack trace`?

Answer (score 1):

If you'll debug your program you'll find out that the following line throws the exception:

```
 retobj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, anytype);
```

The main cause is that the marshalling tool does not know how to marshal your type. This has many possible causes, two of the most common I know are:

1. Nested structures in the struct (of type anytype)

   - solved by prefixing your struct with

   > [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
2. Nested arrays.

   - solved by prefixing array with

   > [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 512)]

Hope it helps.